# Magento 1 - Using html tags in the shipping method title in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'd like to be able to use some simple html tags to format the Shipping Method Title.  If I include tags in the Shipping Method Title currently via the admin panel, it displays the tag on the front end and doesn't treat it as html.

I believe that the class is Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Totals and the method is renderTotals.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use debug Toolbar to find the phtml and add your necessary HTML tags in the phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to override lots and lots of files to achieve such a thing (which covers things like PDFs, Invoices, Emails, Credit Notes, AdminHtml, User Account areas etc).
Search for:

```
"getShippingDescription()"
```

Often you'll have to replace:

```
$this->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingDescription())
```

with:

```
$_order->getShippingDescription()
```

obviously, this would be patching core Magento files, so you could do overrides in your theme (very boring). Both ways would cause problems when upgrading magento if you ask me, so best just to find and replace, and then re-apply the patch next time you upgrade if such a feature is important to you :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the html file responsible for rendering each shipping item in the checkout page is:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-item.html

To override it you need to create the same file in your theme:

> app/design/frontend/PACKAGE-NAME/THEME-NAME/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-item.html

After you have to change the "text" attribute into an "html" for the method title:

Before:

```
<td class="col col-method"
        attr="'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
        text="method.method_title" />
```

After:

```
<td class="col col-method"
        attr="'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
        html="method.method_title" />
```

Remove your cache:

> rm -rf pub/static/* var/cache/* var/generation/* var/di/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/*;

Finally you will be able to add html tags to the shipping method title via admin panel without issues on the checkout page.